# Where is this component's variable coming from during onClick()?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing the [React tic-tac-toe tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), and I just want to know where the initial `i` in this function (within the `Game` class, that is being passed into `handleClick`) comes from exactly:

```
return (
  <div className="game">
    <div className="game-board">
      <Board
        squares={current.squares}
        onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)} // this guy
      />
    </div>
    <div className="game-info">
      <div>{status}</div>
      <ol>{moves}</ol>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

It's not specified in `state` or `props` and isn't produced during `render`.

The full code:

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      history: [{
        squares: Array(9).fill(null)
      }],
      stepNumber: 0,
      xIsNext: true,
    };
  }
  handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      history: history.concat([{
        squares: squares,
      }]),
      stepNumber: history.length,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
    });
  }

  jumpTo(step) {
    this.setState({
      stepNumber: step,
      xIsNext: (step % 2) === 0,
    });
  }
  render() {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

    // history of moves each as a <li>
    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
      const desc = move ?
      'Go to move #' + move :
      'Go to game start';
      return (
        <li key={move}>
          <Button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</Button>
        </li>
      );
    });

    // determine winner
    let status;
    if (winner) {
      status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
    } else {
      status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    }

    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board
            squares={current.squares}
            onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)} // this guy
          />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{status}</div>
          <ol>{moves}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `this.renderSquare(x)` you're passsing the `i`.

So for example you have `this.renderSquare(1)` which triggers the `renderSquare(i)`. The `renderSquare(i)` is used in the state of `Game Component` to create the board.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now - `Game` is rendering the `Board` and specifying `onClick`, as a call to `handleClick`, which is passed to `Board` as props. The `Board` renders a `Square` and defines it's `onClick` call to the function specified in it's props (`handleClick` by `Game`) and passing in `i`...  Thanks again and welcome to stack overflow - you're already killing it =)